# pd.groupby by column + list

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I know how to use `.groupby` over more than one column, namely:

```
df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size()
```

I also know how to use `.groupby` using `a list` that is distinct/separate from the `dataframe` I am working with, namely:

```
df.groupby(aList).size()
```

But how can I use `.groupby` using, simultaneously, a separate `list` and one (or some) of the columns of the `dataframe` I am working with. I.e, what is the correct way to write:

```
df.groupby(aList, aColumnName).size()
```

? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `list`s together with `+`:

```
#for list with one column name
df.groupby(aList + [aColumnName]).size()  
#for join 2 lists
df.groupby(aList + collist2).size()  
#for join with columns
df.groupby(aList + df.columns[:2].tolist()).size()
```

Comment: @Tai - yes, it is alternative. But I can remove it ;)